# alias DOS command for runas

Tags: alias, dos

I'd like to be able to alias a dos command to use in conjunction with the runas command

specifically I'm tired of getting the full path to BIDS (`"C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"`), and I'd like to alias like MS has done for `ssms`.

Anyone know how to do this?  I know I can accomplish this with a batch file, but I'd really rather not.

```
runas /user:user /netonly bids
```

vs.

```
runas /user:user /netonly "C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe"
```

Comment: I referenced this doc: http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb490894.aspx and it looks like that might work.  If you can provide an answer below (rather than a comment), that links to some documentation and provides a working example based on the command listed in the question, the bounty is yours.

Comment: With my method, posted below, you could do it the same as @Jon suggested but the command alias would be pre-loaded when you open the dos shell.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This `doskey` technique is featured over at SuperUser, see https://superuser.com/questions/49170/create-an-alias-in-windows-xp.

The problem with it is that you can't define an alias to be used by `runas`. You could define an alias that included both `runas` *and* the command you want to run, but this would not then be reusable. But what about doing this:

```
SET BIDS=C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\IDE\devenv.exe
DOSKEY r=runas /user:user /netonly "%$1%"
```

Which you can then use like

```
r bids
```

Of course this requires you to set an environment var for each shortcut you 'd like to have, but I think this is no greater requirement than setting the `doskey` alias itself. In any case, it doesn't create a file and it doesn't require that anything be placed in the `path`.

**Update:**

I didn't try it myself, but it certainly looks like you can set it and forget it.

- The environment variables can be set through Windows' system settings (see image)
- The `DOSKEY` alias can be set each time `cmd.exe` starts [using the registry](http://sourcedaddy.com/windows-7/using-autorun-execute-commands-when-command-prompt-starts.html)

[image]

Comment: Brilliant!  Couple of follow on questions.  Is there a way for me to persist this beyond a single session?  This works, but I have to reset it each time I restart the command prompt.

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem you're hitting is that the command line is evaluated as the new user - so unless the new user also has access to your alias, it won't work.

Edit: It's possible you could work around this by creating a conveniently placed batch file (or shortcut?) which launches BIDS and RunAs'ing that?

**Edit:**

See [here](http://www.answers.com/topic/dos-choice) and [here](http://www.robvanderwoude.com/choice.php) for info on the choice command

Sample usage:

```
@ECHO OFF
Echo 1. Some Command
Echo 2. Some Other Command
CHOICE /C:12 /N /T:1,10 Choose an option
IF ERRORLEVEL 2 GOTO COMMAND2
IF ERRORLEVEL 1 GOTO COMMAND1
GOTO END

:COMMAND1
Runas /Uer:Blah "BLAH" > NUL
GOTO END

:COMMAND2
Runas /Uer:Blah "BLAH" > NUL
GOTO END

:END
```

Comment: Yeah, I thought about the batch file before but there are several different scenarios where I do this and I'd really rather not have that many batch files milling about...

Comment: FWIW, I have a single batch file which uses `CHOICE.COM` to provide a menu, do the `RunAs` and prompt for a password - So I just type `RunIt`, Pick an option and type a password. In this scenario, I can also run different pieces of software as different users (My standard acct/My DBA acct for SSMS, etc...)

Comment: How in the world do you do that?  I'm not familiar with choice.com

Comment: Updated my answer. Even though you need to DL Choice, It's very handy (it can also be used for a timed pause in batch files). It works on windows 98/2K/XP/Vista/7

Comment: You could even present multiple menus - eg Menu 1 pick user, store it in a variable. MEnu 2, pick the app - Then combine the 2 to run the app as the specified user

Comment: Awesome answer - thanks a ton.  I'm accepting the other because it doesn't require additional installs, but I'll undoubtedly use this in the future.  Thanks again!

Comment: Well, if I don't get the bounty, upvotes are always appreciated :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is a script that will setup alias's on your command shells.  This script gives you the elusive "WHERE" command :

```
@ECHO OFF 
ECHO Loading additional commands from:
ECHO    %0
ECHO Type 'DOSKEY /MACROS:ALL' to see the configured commands.
:: to install, place this .bat script in the location you want 
:: it to reside and then run this batch script with the argument "register"
IF "%1"=="register" (
  REG.exe ADD "HKCU\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\Autorun" /ve /t REG_SZ /d "%0" /f
  ECHO The DOS profile is registered.  Load a new command prompt and test a command.
)
@DOSKEY LS=DIR /w 
@DOSKEY CP=COPY $* 
@DOSKEY MV=MOVE $* 
@DOSKEY H=DOSKEY /HISTORY
@DOSKEY WHERE=@for %%e in (%PATHEXT%) do @for %%i in ($*%%e) do @if NOT "%%~$PATH:i"=="" echo %%~$PATH:i
```

Comment: Interesting alternative. +1

Comment: The script doesn't work on every Win7 system... not sure why, but it works on 2 of my computers.